# Como manter fixa parte de uma v-model(string) em um input com VueJS!

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tenho um input text com sua respectiva model, porém preciso que uma parte desse valor seja fixa, por exemplo: `/static/download.jpg` a ideia é que o usuário só consiga alterar o texto que está depois de `/static/`.. mantendo essa parte fixa na model.

Tendei implementar uma regra no `@input` e `@change` mais não deu muito certo.. Alguma sugestão?

Obrigado!

Edit: Tentei uma implementação aqui com o evento `@change` no input.. mais em alguns momentos ele inclui mais de uma vez a `/` após o `/static/`, segue o trecho de código a seguir!

```js
var initialModel1 = '/static/teste.jpg';
var initialModel2 = 'teste.jpg';
var initialModel3 = '';

function test(model) {

  if (model.indexOf('/static/') === 0) {
    model = `/static/${model.substr(8)}`;

    console.log(model)
    return;
  }

  if (model !== '') {
    model = `/static/${model}`;

    console.log(model)
    return;
  }

  model = `/static/`;
  console.log(model)
}

test(initialModel1);
test(initialModel2);
test(initialModel3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Você deve utilizar observadores para isso, veja:

html:

```
...
<input type="text" v-model="input">
...
```

vuejs:

```
...
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            ...
            input:'/static/'
        }
    },
    watch:{
        input: function(value){
            return '/static/'.value
        }
    }
}
```

Obviamente meu exemplo é bem grosso e existem formas melhores de fazer como por exemplo prefixar isso com um tipo de inputgroup do bootstrap por exemplo e pegar só o que o usuário digita e presumir no backend que o que for inserido entra após o caminho... depende muito do resultado final. Como você foi genérico na dúvida eu respondi de forma geral mais para ilustrar o conceito.

Este link aqui pode lhe ser útil:

https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Dados-Computados-vs-Observadores